# ModelForm view not saving or

Tags: django

I am trying to implement ModelForm, I am having a problem where the model not only does not save, but also does not redirect on post. I did not have these problems when I just wrote the forms directly as HTML.

models.py:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey('ZipCode')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=False, blank=True )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields= ['foo',]

class FooBar(forms.ModelForm):  

    title= forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="FooBar title")
    description = forms.CharField(help_text="FooBar description",
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'paceholder':'Please enter your description'}))       
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Movement
    exclude = ['foo']
```

view.py:

```
def new_foobar(request):
    template_name = 'new_foobar.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        foo_form = fooForm(data=request.POST)
        foobar_form = FooBarForm(data=request.POST)

        if foo_form.is_valid() and foobar_form.is_valid():
            foo, create = FooBar.objects.get_or_create(**form.cleaned_data)
            foobar = foobar_form.save(commit=False)
            foobar.foo = foo
            foobar.save(commit=True)    
            return redirect('/results/%d' %zipcode.id)

    else:
        foo_form = FooForm()
        foobar_form = FooBarForm()
```

Comment: Please, first, update your question with code that make sense, that code won't work. `**form.cleaned_data`, but `form` doesn't exist, the same with `movement_form`. Your view is not returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean?:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that does not get my test to pass.